# Wagtail / Django- images don't display in wagtail admin when published on a production server

Tags: django, docker, wagtail, production

I'm using Docker, PostgreSQL, Gunicorn and nginx. I've searched for the answer everywhere. All works fine on the development server.

When I publish to the production server the images do not display in wagtail admin.

**Dockerfile.prod**

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/wa-cms

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install Wagtail, Django and psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add \
    postgresql-dev \ 
    gcc \
    python3-dev \
    musl-dev \
    build-base \
    jpeg-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    openjpeg-dev

# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir
RUN pip install flake8
COPY . .


# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt . 
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/wa-cms/wheels -r requirements.txt


######################
# FINAL - PRODUCTION #
######################

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/static
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/media
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq \
    postgresql-dev \ 
    gcc \
    python3-dev \
    musl-dev \
    build-base \
    jpeg-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    openjpeg-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/wa-cms/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/wa-cms/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh $APP_HOME

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

**docker-compose.prod.yml**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./wa-cms
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn backend.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media
    restart: unless-stopped 
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
    restart: unless-stopped 
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web
  
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream wtwacmsdev01 {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://wtwacmsdev01;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/web/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/app/web/media/;
    }

}
```

**I run the commands:**

```
chmod +x wa-cms/entrypoint.prod.sh

docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --build

winpty docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec web python manage.py migrate --noinput

winpty docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec web python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
```

If anybody can give any indication as to what I am doing wrong that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which images? Ones in static or ones in media? 

I would try switching to DEBUG=False in your dev environment and see if that allows you to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply cnk. The images which I've uploaded into wagtail pages. they all show as grey boxes in the wagtail's images folder. I've changed DEBUG to False  in dev.py and got Internal server error. I've changed it back to True and it's working fine again with images showing in wagtail. When I click any of the images in wagtail in production I get an error in nginx logs that there is no such file or directory.  *1630 open() "/home/app/web/media/images/shutterstock_1706533444_a7DfDtI.max-165x165.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory),

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling to suggest options because I can't really imagine using a Docker volume for storing user-uploaded content in production. Dev, yes. But for production I usually have the files stored in S3 so they are always available and have backups. Something like the code below:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME', default=None)
if AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME:
    # https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
    MEDIA_ROOT = ''
    MEDIA_URL = "http://{}.s3.amazonaws.com/".format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', default='us-west-2')
    AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = True
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'private'
else:
    # Use a docker volume 
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'catalog.core.utils.FileSystemStorage'
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#media-root
    MEDIA_ROOT = '/media'  # noqa
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#media-url
    MEDIA_URL = ''
```

Comment: Many thanks for your comment and for sharing the code. I'll look into removing volumes and storing the content somewhere else.